# How to setup/map remote mysql db in local phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I am working on a remote development server. I have the mysql host name, db name, user name , password of that remote server. I want to setup/replicate/map that dev server mysql in my local phpmyadmin, so that I can access the remote server db locally(for ex :- /mylocalip/remote-server-db).
Thus I don't have to do ssh connection and open the mysql in terminal. How can we do this in phpmyadmin/config.inc.php.

Let me explain again through an example. Lets say the remote server db is accessible through 213.81.203.130/phpmyadmin. I want to access that db from my local ip through an alias name by creating a mapping i.e 192.168.10.140/remote-db. Basically this can be done by adding some sort of code in phpmyadmin/config.inc.php or config.db.php. But how to do it I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid using terminal, why not try **[MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/)** to connect to the database?

**UPDATE**

In light of all the views to this question, I am adding a solution that more accurately matches the question. Please see [this link](http://digitalmemo.neobie.net/2010/10/12/connecting-to-multiple-database-on-phpmyadmin/), I believe it will be helpful. It involves editing the phpmyadmin config.inc.php file to add additional servers. This is how you can keep your localhost connection, and add any remote db connections. Simply select the server from the drop down at the login screen to phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 methods to set this up

METHOD #1 : MySQL Replication

Setup MySQL Replication where the Slave has this option

```
replicate_do_table=mydb.mytable
```

Then, any DML (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) or DDL (ALTER TABLE) you execute will go immediately to serverB. This makes Method #1 is the fastest and most granular approach.

METHOD #2 : Copying the table to the other server

Rather than rehash, Here is an earlier post, Mr. RolandoMySQLDBA did May 31, 2011 for this method : [How do you copy a table from MySqlServer_A to MySqlServer_B?][1]

METHOD #3 : FEDERATED Table (MyISAM Only)

Suppose mytable on serverA looks like this

> CREATE TABLE mydb.mytable ( ... ) ENGINE=MyISAM;

You can a mapping of the target table in serverB by running this on serverA like this

> CREATE TABLE mydb.mytable_remote LIKE mytable; ALTER TABLE
>   mydb.mytable_remote ENGINE=FEDERATED
>   CONNECTION='mysql://username:password@serverB/mydb/mytable';

Comment: Hi Harjeet, let me explain again through an example. Lets say the remote server db is accessible through 213.81.203.130/phpmyadmin. I want to access that db from my local ip through an alias name, through mapping i.e 192.168.10.140/remote-db. Basically this can be done by adding some sort of code in phpmyadmin/config.inc.php or config.db.php. But how to do it i am not sure