# In phpMyAdmin, how to enter 'remote' MySQL info (not local)?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

background:

1. There is a Q on this in the SE history but the comment-link is 404. [How to setup/map remote mysql db in local phpmyadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14995959/how-to-setup-map-remote-mysql-db-in-local-phpmyadmin)
2. The answer to this sort-of (I apparently do not understand it correctly) is in the phpMyAdmin documentation http://phpmyadmin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config.html#server-connection-settings

I have a remote MySQL on a typical Apache shared public webserver (with WordPress and SimpleMachines involved with it online). I want to be able to connect to my remote databases, clone (or whatever the word) that structure on my local (windows8) machine, and then do an official full backup (which I hope to restore, after re-installing s/w) of my MySQL online databases.

What I did so far:

Installed Uniserver Zero XI including phpMyAdmin.

In the phpMyAdmin files, I opened config.inc.php and I see the

/* Servers configuration */

```
$i = 0;
```

/* Server: localhost [1] */

```
$i++;
```

/* Authentication section */
/* Server parameters */

the latter two followed by many lines with iterative reference and settings, such as:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config'; // Authentication method 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root'; // MySQL user
```

etc.

Docs say to just copy the whole server block part(s) and put in settings, for additional servers. Sounds easy enough.

When I do this, phpMyAdmin doesn't even open anymore (in the browser window), just a white screen. When I delete the added blocks of text, it's fine again.

I was putting the new block below the existing block. Am I putting it in the wrong place? Is there someplace where it should be outside or after the 'iterative loop' for numbering (where would that be)?

Or is there something I should do up in the first two lines with the i's?

I apologize for my ignorance, but, that's why I have a question. The documentation seems to assume I know, and googling finds me 10 gazillion hits unrelated, except the one former SE question with a link that was 404.

Comment: Please provide your version of phpMyAdmin configuration file here or show a part where servers defined (of course, remove passwords if they specified there).

Comment: '/* Servers configuration */
$i = 0;

/* Server: localhost [1] */
$i++;

/* Authentication section */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']       = 'config';  // Authentication method (config, http or cookie based)?
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']            = 'root';    // MySQL user
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']        = $password; // MySQL password (only needed with 'config' auth_type)
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;     // Must use password

more to come, I'm limited to a few chars in this comment box

Comment: /* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose']      = 'Uniform Server'; // Verbose name for this host - leave blank to show the hostname
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']         = '127.0.0.1';      // MySQL hostname or IP address
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']         = $port_ini;        // Port set in ini See above
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket']       = '';               // Leave blank for default socket
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';            // How to connect to MySQL server ('tcp' or 'socket')

Comment: $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension']    = 'mysqli';         // MySQL extension to use ('mysql' or 'mysqli')
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress']     = false;            // No compression

Comment: That really didn't work very well. Lemme screenshot it and link to the image, back shortly.

Comment: This is the default file in phpMyAdmin. The docs (linked in my OP) suggest just a copy of the code with the new info in it. There must be something more since that seems to break phpMyAdmin even loading (white screen). 
http://palyne.com/code/snap_00787.jpg

Answer (score 1):

What is the name of your config file and location on your disk?

The first line, before what's already there, should be `<?php`. The variable `$port_ini` doesn't seem to be set nor is this standard phpMyAdmin usage, so I would hardcode the port number here (I'm assuming it's nonstandard since you've included it in the configuration, if it is the default 3306 you can just remove that line entirely).

Same thing with `$password`, unless you've actually defined that somewhere and modified phpMyAdmin to use your new variable name that isn't a defined variable yet and is very possibly the cause of your trouble; hard code the password here (or better yet, switch to auth_type cookie and remove the user and password lines entirely).

Check your webserver error log for details; if it's logging errors you should see a lot more detail there about what is causing the exact problem.

Comment: removing the port number helps me